# Read preference for Mongodb queries within a secondary node

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, replicaset

I know that it is possible run execure a single command within a secondary node like:

```
Mongoid.default_session.cluster.with_secondary do |node|
  node.command(database, cmd)["result"]
end
```

But is there a way to perform a piece of code containing multiple database queries with Mongoid 3 like it is implemented in [mongo-ruby-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/wiki/Read-Preference)

```
with_secondary do
  user = User.find(id)
  user.posts.each do |post|
    post.comments.count
  end
end
```

so every query to be performed within secondary node?